# Mixed Content: The page at [url] was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest , Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I got this error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://url.app/admin' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://url.app/json/questions?search=&page=1&per_page=20&sort_by=&sort_direction=asc'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

The rest of the requests works fine, not sure why I got an error on this route.
I am using Laravel / Vue. All routes are in web.php (If I access the url from error I got data from server.)

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your HTML file,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you are sending the request `/json/questions` over HTTP not HTTPS. 
Try to change it to HTTPS and see what will happen.

Comment: What to change? My request are on HTTPS, I have 2/3 that are on HTTP, but I am not sure why, because I don't do somethins special for them to be on HTTP.

Comment: Check how the URL is build before sending the request. Can you provide a code snippet for this part ?